# autohotkey "Send" troubleshoot

Tags: autohotkey

I want to automate UI clicking, I have the following script.

```
F2::
WinActivate, NoVirusThanks MAC Address Changer v1.0
F3::
ControlClick, TListView1, NoVirusThanks MAC Address Changer v1.0
F4::Send, {Tab}
```

My problem is, ControlClick is not working, and this is what I have tried.

I doubt if title is wrong, but WinActivate is working, so nope.
I doubt if hotkeys are conflicted, but WinActivate still works if assigned as F3.
I doubt if ControlClick is misused, so I try Send {Tab}, but the app doesn't navigate between widgets, which is not expected.
I press tab on physical keyboard, and it does move focus, navigate between buttons.

What should I suspect now?

Comment: Okay, WinActivate works because I always have to switch to other widows before doing it. It looks like when I activate the windows, none of the hotkeys would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself, so it looks like it has something to do with UAC & administrator mode. What make send not working is because the app is run as admin.

Solution:
Run script as admin works fine on me.
This [post](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/70449-enable-interaction-with-administrative-programs/) for more discussion.

Comment: ControlClick still not working though, doubt if it's same kind of issue.